# Angular 7 formGroup is undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using angular 7 and creating a modal as a component to be used on related part of my SPA. when i click the button that opens the modal i receive an error;
I am using angular 7 and creating a modal as a component to be used on related part of my SPA. when i click the button that opens the modal i receive an error;

> ERROR TypeError: "_co.formGroup is undefined"

this is my code

html

```
    <form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(formGroup.value)">
  <h2 class="dialog-form-title">SIGN UP</h2>

  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Email" formControlName="email">
    <mat-error *ngIf="!formGroup.controls['email'].valid && formGroup.controls['email'].touched">
      {{ getErrorEmail() }}
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Full Name" formControlName="name">
    <mat-error *ngIf="!formGroup.controls['name'].valid && formGroup.controls['name'].touched">

    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput formControlName="role" placeholder="Role">
    <mat-error *ngIf="!formGroup.controls['role'].valid && formGroup.controls['role'].touched">

    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput formControlName="orgId" placeholder="Organization Id">
    <mat-error *ngIf="!formGroup.controls['orgId'].valid && formGroup.controls['orgId'].touched">

    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput formControlName="orgName" placeholder="Organization Name">
    <mat-error *ngIf="!formGroup.controls['orgName'].valid && formGroup.controls['orgName'].touched">

    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput type="password" formControlName="password" placeholder="Password">
    <mat-error *ngIf="!formGroup.controls['password'].valid && formGroup.controls['password'].touched">

    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput type="password" formControlName="confirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" ngModel required>
    <mat-error *ngIf="!formGroup.controls['confirmPassword'].valid && formGroup.controls['confirmPassword'].touched">

    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>

  <input type="hidden" name="enable" id="enable" value="true">

  <div class="dialog-form-footer">

    <div class="clearfix"><button mat-flat-button class="green-button" type="submit"
        [disabled]="formGroup.invalid">Submit</button></div>

  </div>
  <div class="top"><a id="closeT" (click)="close()">
      <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
    </a></div>
</form>
```

and this is my ts code

TS

```
  submitted = false;
  formGroup: FormGroup;
  titleAlert: string = "This field is required";

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private element: ElementRef,
    private dialog: MatDialog,
    private service: AuthService,
    private snackBar: MatSnackBar,
    private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<SignupComponent>
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm() {
    let emailregex: RegExp = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: ["", [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(emailregex)]],
      name: ["", Validators.required],
      role: ["", Validators.required],
      orgId: ["", Validators.required],
      orgName: ["", Validators.required],
      password: ["", [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
      confirmPassword: ["", [Validators.required, this.passwordValidator]]
    });
  }

  get name() {
    return this.formGroup.get("name") as FormControl;
  }

  passwordValidator(form) {
    const condition =
      this.formGroup.get("password").value !==
      this.formGroup.get("confirmPassword").value;

    return condition ? { passwordsDoNotMatch: true } : null;
  }


  onSubmit(post) {
    console.log(post.value);
    // console.log(form.value);
    const test = post.controls.orgName.value;
    console.log("test sigup:" + test);


    this.service.signupform(post.value).subscribe(
      res => {
        this.dialogRef.close();
        this.snackBar.open(`Success!`, "OK", snackBarConfig);
      },
      err => {
        this.dialogRef.close();
        this.snackBar.open(`Cannot Proses!` + err, "OK", snackBarConfig);
        console.log("check error:" + err);
      }
    );
  }
  close() {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
```

Hope you all can help

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

I have fork in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gbel4v-atdkzn) and just got error

> Unexpected value 'undefined' declared by the module 'AppModule'

Comment: Please create a Working Sample Stackblitz replicating this issue. There are a lot of unknowns as of now. Without those, it's hard to figure out what the issue is.

Comment: You can fork **[this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gbel4v?file=app/form-field-overview-example.ts)** to get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that, `passwordValidator` access multiple FormControls, `password` and `confirmPassword`, thus you should bind that validator to the entire FormGroup, rather than the `confirmPassword` FormControl itself.

Therefore, on your component.ts, on the createForm method, this is what you should be using:

```
createForm() {
  let emailregex: RegExp = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    email: ["", [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(emailregex)]],
    name: ["", Validators.required],
    role: ["", Validators.required],
    orgId: ["", Validators.required],
    orgName: ["", Validators.required],
    password: ["", [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
    confirmPassword: ["", [Validators.required]]
  }, {
    validator: this.passwordValidator
  });
}
```

And then, on your validator method,

```
passwordValidator(form: FormGroup) {
  const condition =
    form.value.password !==
    form.value.confirmPassword;

  return condition ? { passwordsDoNotMatch: true } : null;
}
```

I have replicated a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gbel4v-bgpfwy?file=app/form-field-overview-example.ts) for you, as well as adding a flag on the component.html that actually displays the error message if the passwords do not match.

Comment: that the problem... thank you so much dude... it work... you save my day

Comment: @Shah You are welcome! If you are still unclear, you can refer to the demo I created above.

Comment: Sorry.. I have 1 more question... why submit button still disable. Although I have filled all the form..

Comment: Hmm... Are you sure you have filled in all the forms? And the password fields are valid? I have tried it on the demo I made, and it seems to work..

Comment: No worries :) Glad to help! Let me know if you are facing more issues

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196547/discussion-between-shah-and-wentjun).